# Javascript send two parameters on OnClick (HTML/PHP)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code passing **one** parameter (user_id) on onclick:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#user_id').val('<?=$v['user_id']?>')" data-id="<?=$v['user_id']?>"></a>
```

But i need pass **two** parameters (user_id and group_id), like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#user_id').val('<?=$v['user_id']?>') $('#group_id').val('<?=$v['group_id']?>')" data-id="<?=$v['user_id'], $v['group_id']?>"></a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: your code doesn't send anything

Comment: Seems like you need to perform two *actions* on click, not pass two parameters. The solution would be creating a function that takes both parameters and performs the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom function to do multiple action at once like this

```
<script>
          function myAction(user_id, group_id){
            console.log(user_id, group_id);
            $('#user_id').val(user_id);
            $('#group_id').val(group_id);
          }
        </script>
        <a href="#" onclick="myAction('<?=$v['user_id']?>', '<?=$v['group_id']?>')" data-group-id="'<?=$v['group_id']?>'" data-user-id="'<?=$v['group_id']?>'">Click It</a>
```

or your can do it simply by adding a semicolon to execute multiple statements on a single onclick, as follows

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#user_id').val('<?=$v['user_id']?>');$('#group_id').val('<?=$v['group_id']?>')" data-id="<?=$v['user_id'], $v['group_id']?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
<a href="#" onclick="() => {
   $('#user_id').val('<?=$v['user_id']?>');
   console.log($v['group_id']);
}" data-id="<?=$v['user_id']?>"></a>
```